# Node version inconsistent in crontab

Tags: node.js, cron, nvm, amazon-linux

I regularly at version 8.4.0, then I installed nvm and used it to upgrade to version 9.11.1.
When running the terminal, I have version 9.11.1, however if a conjob runs a script, node 8.4.0 is still used.
The same ec2-user is running the cron so for me it is strange that the user ec2-user has version 9.11.1 if used via shell and 8.4.0 if used via cron.

How can I resolve this to always use 9.11.1?

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely using just `node` or `/usr/local/bin/node` to refer to node, instead of `/usr/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/bin/node`